# How to I get my images to stay contained within their our div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have a two images and a ul list contained within a div. At full page they all stay contained within the div (first image below), but when I resize the page the the images and ul list move accordingly but they're no longer contained within the div (second image below). Does anyone know how I can change this?

[image: here]

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="more">


  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="social-logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="" alt="" width="200" height="200"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="links">
    <ul class="about">
      <li class="a-links">
        <div id="about-links" class="site-content">
          <ul class="aboutli">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Work With Us</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12" id="drinkaware">
      <a href="https://drinkaware.co.uk"><img src="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/D0.1/images/drinkawarered.png" width="200" height="auto"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.more {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
#social-logo {
  display: inline-block;

}
ul.about {
  width: 160px;
  height: 184px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  list-style-type: none !important;
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 0.8cm;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul.aboutli {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none !important;
}
#drinkaware {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Talk is cheap, show us the code

Comment: Accidentally pressed enter but it's up now.

Comment: Definitely some missing code here, tell us the whole story.

Comment: `.more` has a height prop set, and its not expanding with its children as you crush down to mobile. Which is how it works. you need a height : auto and a clearing element to accommodate the floating children. or use flexbox.

Comment: Nope that's all the code. There's a body wrapper around it all with I haven't added any CSS to, just left bootstrap's default CSS to do its thing.

Comment: Flexbox worked a charm! Thank you @Bosworth99. I'd happily accept your answer if you submit one.

Comment: @TDP - glad that helps. answer posted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height property of .more, or add `overflow: auto;` to it.
If you want all the elements side by side add `float: left;` to #social-logo, col-sm-3 col-xs-12, and col-sm-3 col-xs-12

Answer (score 0):

`.more` has a `height` prop set, and its not expanding with its children as you crush down to mobile. Which is how it works. You need a `height : auto` and a clearing element to accommodate the floating children, potentially as part of a media query, if you really need `height : 300px` at desktop.

Or just use `display:flexbox` on the containing element.

[Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)